# Create a static_front_page via function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function or hook where I can set a static front page in my `functions.php` file?

I want to create an install class which create menus, widgets and a static front page.

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you wish to just set a static template programmatically or make it dynamic depending on the request or similar? You can update the `wp_options` table with `set_option` and change the front page template there. If you just want to set it as usual, you can set it in the `wp-admin` settings page. When the setting is set, WordPress loads the theme template `front-page.php`.

Comment: I just want to set it once in the wp_options. But i couldn't find a option like "front page template" in my wp_options table.

Comment: The switch to load a static template is `show_on_front` in `wp_options`. It defaults to `posts` but I think the other value is `page` or similar.

Comment: @ojrask this is the trick! Ive set the show_on_fronts to "page" and page_on_front to the specific id. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**This is quite simple as it's handled by Wordpress core :**

1. Make a page template (e.g. my-static-front-page.php) starting with :

   ```
   <?php
    /*
    * Template Name: My static front page template
    * Description: A new custom front page for my website
     */
    ?>
   ```

   *Now, your php file can be set as a Page Template.*
2. Create a new Page in your Wordpress admin and set the relevant page template :

[image]

*Now you're Page will be rendered with your Page Template (no matter any Template Hierarchy consideration).*

3. In the Wordpress admin, set a static front page in Settings > Reading :

[image]

*Now your page is set as the front_page.*

There you go. From what I know, this is a really reliable solution to handle static front page with Wordpress.

*You could for sure use template hierarchy and simply use front-page.php or home.php. But Wordpress users won't be able to edit it.*

Comment: So, i just want your step 3 as a function in my backend. Ive already written a install class for the theme, wich creates menus and widgets after the theme is switched. And i want to set the step 3. in my class too. The administrators who choose my theme should see after every theme switch the defined static front page and standard menus, without doing this things manually as you described it.

Comment: So your question is very unclear, reformulate it please. As said by ojrask, show_on_front in wp_options will do the job. But the thing is, you'll need to select a Page ID. So you need to create a page during your installation and set it as the show_on_front options. But I guess you won't create a Page in your theme installation (that would be annoying for the users).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a function, but if you're making a theme, you could just include a front-page.php template file, which is automatically used as front page regardless of admin settings.

Comment: Hey Thomas, this is a solution, but if i choose the front-page.php the Admins couldn't change the static front Page if they want to.